# Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to install Viber

Tags: 18.04, viber

I am trying to get Viber on my new Ubuntu 18.04 but I get these error ...

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/viber.deb 
(Reading database ... 138136 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Downloads/viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (7.0.0.1035) over (7.0.0.1035) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libcurl3; however:
  Package libcurl3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package viber (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber
```

Comment: Looks like the Viber people need to provide a package for 18.04 (or if this was one for Ubuntu 18.04 then they need to fix it) so that it depends on the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

UPDATE:
The same issue arises when you try to install the newest viber 12.0.0.7 in ubuntu 20.04 (at least the beta until now), but with the problematic dependency being libssl1.0. Ubuntu has libssl1.1 installed.

The solution is the exactly the same, just use the corresponding names.

The problem is not only with the `viber.deb` file but also with the `libcurl3` requirement of `viber.deb`.

In Ubuntu 18.04 `libcurl3` cannot coexist with `libcurl4` so you are going to face problems with other applications. In my case Viber and Steam could not coexist.

After some search I found the following solution which is to deb-package, fix the dependency and then build a new viber file.

The steps are:

1. Save the `viber.deb` file in a folder
2. Open the folder in a terminal
3. execute the following commands
4. `dpkg-deb -x viber.deb viber`
5. `dpkg-deb --control viber.deb viber/DEBIAN`
6. Edit `viber/DEBIAN/control` and replace "libcurl3" with "libcurl4"
   (also delete the last blank line from the file or you will get an error afterwards)
7. `dpkg -b viber viberlibcurl4.deb`
8. `sudo dpkg -i viberlibcurl4.deb` or install the `.deb` file with `gdebi`

Viber seems to work ok with `libcurl4` atleast for me until now.

I found the solution here, in a comment...

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: How is still not fixed by viber themselves?

Comment: Rakuten is a company. They make shareholders happy. Shareholders are happy when 95% of users  are happy. 95% of users are happy when windows/osx/android/ios versions work.

Comment: Hope it's OK if I bump in here: the above doesn't work for me. When I try it, or when I try to install viber with the "software-center" on ubuntu, nothing happens. I did all the above, but when I type ´viber´ into the terminal, it says the command isn't found, and ´which viber´ gives nothing too.

Comment: It appears somehow the link to viber didn't get put on my system path? I found ´viber.desktop´ in ´/usr/share/applications/´, and with ´cat´ turns out there is an executable in ´/opt/viber/Viber´, which seems to run Viber. However, what does this mean? Does the system not look for executable files there, and if so, why did Viber get put there? How do I make it "visibile" to the system with ´which´, when running from terminal or when searching for the application?

Comment: This does help. However, the Viber now runs and only white dialogs are shown... (but I observed that Viber is actually running). This happened with the recent update of some components. I contacted the Viber Support and they do not plan to release new updates. Any idea how to solve this new issue?

Comment: I also have the problem of a white screen.  One answer said to run as sudo, but there is no viber file in usr/bin

Comment: I was able to get this working by installing the snap listed below viber-unofficial

Comment: @D.Dan, https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMjli.png

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libcurl3 viber.deb
```

Works perfectly for me.

**Update:** @borowis is right: after installing this way it gets uninstalled on fix broken dependencies.
Another one line, but still workable solution is:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3 ~/viber.deb
```

*source*: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: viber works but I got "Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)"

Comment: This solution is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to convert the rpm package on Viber website to a deb package. To do that:

Download the rpm package with:

```
wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.rpm
```

Install alien, convert the rpm package and install the newly created deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien --to-deb --scripts viber.rpm
sudo dpkg -i viber_7.0.0.1035-3_amd64.deb
```

The conversion will take about 5 minutes. Be patient!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind to use snap, you can install Viber easily from Snap Store:

```
sudo snap install viber-unofficial
```

**Disclaimer:** I've added this snap to snap store.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution now.  The previous accepted answer is no longer working.  Snap was invented to solve this very exact problem

Comment: This is great and it worked. However the package is outdated and is still on version 7.0

Comment: The Viber app previously had an issue with high DPI screens, making it appear too large and unusable. `viber-unofficial` has the same problem. With `Viber` it was fixable by setting an environment variable (QT_SCALE_FACTOR), e.g. in the .desktop file. But for some reason it's not working for me with viber-unofficial. Is the .desktop file always read from /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications ?

Answer (score 3):

The solution to installing Viber on Ubuntu 18.04 is to explicitly include the `libcurl3` package prerequisite as part of the apt installation command:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3 ~/Downloads/viber.deb
```

[How to install Viber on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

You can also just install the [flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.viber.Viber) from flathub.org

Comment: 'Warning' section from 'Install Viber'  from your link seems to be working great. I advise everyone try it with libcurl4

Answer (score 1):

After trying some above answers I found another solution. There is a `cURL` **PPA** which supports both `cURL` version 3 and 4.

https://launchpad.net/~xapienz/+archive/ubuntu/curl34

So, I added this **PPA** to my *Ubuntu 18.04* and installed `cURL` from there. Then I installed ***Viber*** with this below command-

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

And ***Viber*** is working fine till then.

> ***No broken package warning till now and `libcurl4` package is installed***.

Comment: This only works on 18.04, not 18.10 as there is no PPA for 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to install single deb-packages it to use APT-tool, which will solve all dependencies automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install ./Downloads/viber.deb
```

Comment: I don't think it can work unless the problem between libcurl version 3 and 4 is fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `libcurl3` and remove `libcurl4`.

All the programs as far as I know, like *Opera* and *Brackets* work fine with either.

Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

When asked for confirmation press <kbd>y</kbd>

This will automatically remove all libcurl4 and it's dependencies and install libcurl3.

As a precaution do:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

to fix any dependency issues that may occur.

Now download the *viber debian package* from their official site.

In terminal type

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
sudo install -f
```

This should install *viber* without any trouble.

Now open *viber* from launchpad.

Happy chatting in *viber* :)

Answer (score 0):

Viber released version 10.30, so this problem is solved. I recommend the installation of the latest version.

Comment: It doesn't install for me.