# Installing libcurl3 without removing R installation

Tags: 18.04, r

I am trying to install `libcurl3` in my system. `libcurl4` is already installed in my system.

[image]

The problem is, installation process is removing my R installation with installed packages.

```
user@len-lin:~$ sudo apt install libcurl3
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdbs dh-translations fonts-glewlwyd fonts-mathjax intltool jq libblas-dev libc-ares2 libhttp-parser2.7.1 libjq1
  libjs-bootstrap libjs-d3 libjs-es5-shim libjs-highlight.js libjs-jquery-datatables libjs-jquery-metadata
  libjs-jquery-selectize.js libjs-jquery-tablesorter libjs-jquery-ui libjs-json libjs-mathjax libjs-microplugin.js
  libjs-sifter.js libjs-twitter-bootstrap libjs-twitter-bootstrap-datepicker liblapack-dev libncurses5-dev libnlopt0
  libonig4 libqt5multimedia5 libreadline-dev libtinfo-dev libuv1 node-highlight.js nodejs nodejs-doc python3-scour
  r-doc-html scour
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev littler r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-base-html r-cran-amelia r-cran-animation
  r-cran-assertthat r-cran-bindr r-cran-bindrcpp r-cran-bitops r-cran-boot r-cran-cairo r-cran-cairodevice r-cran-car
  r-cran-cardata r-cran-caret r-cran-catools r-cran-class r-cran-cli r-cran-cluster r-cran-clustergeneration
  r-cran-codetools r-cran-colorspace r-cran-crayon r-cran-crosstalk r-cran-curl r-cran-cvst r-cran-data.table
  r-cran-ddalpha r-cran-deoptimr r-cran-devtools r-cran-dichromat r-cran-digest r-cran-dimred r-cran-dplyr r-cran-drr
  r-cran-e1071 r-cran-evaluate r-cran-filehash r-cran-foreach r-cran-foreign r-cran-gdata r-cran-ggplot2 r-cran-git2r
  r-cran-glue r-cran-gmodels r-cran-gower r-cran-gplots r-cran-gregmisc r-cran-gridextra r-cran-gtable r-cran-gtools
  r-cran-highr r-cran-hms r-cran-htmltools r-cran-htmlwidgets r-cran-httpuv r-cran-httr r-cran-ipred r-cran-iterators
  r-cran-jsonlite r-cran-kernlab r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-knitr r-cran-labeling r-cran-lattice r-cran-lava
  r-cran-lazyeval r-cran-littler r-cran-lme4 r-cran-lubridate r-cran-magrittr r-cran-maps r-cran-markdown r-cran-mass
  r-cran-matrix r-cran-matrixmodels r-cran-memoise r-cran-mgcv r-cran-mime r-cran-minqa r-cran-misctools
  r-cran-modelmetrics r-cran-multicore r-cran-munsell r-cran-nlme r-cran-nloptr r-cran-nlp r-cran-nnet r-cran-numderiv
  r-cran-openssl r-cran-pbkrtest r-cran-pillar r-cran-pkgconfig r-cran-pkgkitten r-cran-plyr r-cran-png r-cran-prodlim
  r-cran-purrr r-cran-quantreg r-cran-r6 r-cran-rcolorbrewer r-cran-rcpp r-cran-rcppeigen r-cran-rcpproll r-cran-rcurl
  r-cran-readr r-cran-recipes r-cran-reshape r-cran-reshape2 r-cran-rgl r-cran-rlang r-cran-robustbase r-cran-rpart
  r-cran-rstudioapi r-cran-scales r-cran-sfsmisc r-cran-shiny r-cran-slam r-cran-sourcetools r-cran-sparsem
  r-cran-spatial r-cran-stringi r-cran-stringr r-cran-survival r-cran-tibble r-cran-tidyr r-cran-tidyselect
  r-cran-tikzdevice r-cran-timedate r-cran-timeseries r-cran-tkrplot r-cran-tm r-cran-utf8 r-cran-viridislite
  r-cran-whisker r-cran-withr r-cran-xml2 r-cran-xtable r-cran-yaml r-recommended uget
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 145 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Need to get 214 kB of archives.
After this operation, 195 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Is there any way installing `libcurl3` without removing R? Some of the softwares I want to use require `libcurl3`.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to install development package, not binary one. So for compilation of some R-package you need to run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

Comment: As you see in the synaptic screenshot, libcurl4-openssl-dev is already installed. I want to install viber that requires libcurl3. But it wants to remove my R installation. I am trying to find a way to install libcurl3 side by side with libcurl4.

Comment: It seems to be impossible because of the fact that both packages share one file */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4* (see file lists for [`libcurl3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libcurl3/filelist) and [`libcurl4`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libcurl4/filelist)). You can try to contact Viber support about your dependencies problem.

Comment: Just leaving (this solution)[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber] here for those who want to install viber which depends of libcurl3.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xapienz/curl34
sudo apt policy curl
sudo apt remove curl libcurl4
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt install curl=7.58.0-2ubuntu3ppa2 libcurl4=7.58.0-2ubuntu3ppa2
```

or

```
sudo apt install libcurl4
```

This will install libcurl4 package, which supports both libcurl3 and libcurl4 API. Then you do need to install another libcurl3 package for your system.