# Viber installed but missing after some time

Tags: viber

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Viber before three weeks and everything be fine. Yesterday I shut down my laptop and there is no viber on startup. I tryed start viber by myself but I cant find app in installed programs. I am sure that I am not unistall app! What can I do? If I reinstall viber will I have same probler again?

Comment: The problem is in libcurl3 requirement of viber.It cann't coexist with libcurl4. Try this solution:[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, viber app worked pretty well, but several days ago I turned on my computer and didn't find viber app. No icon in dock, no application in list of all applications. It's weird and I have no idea how to solve this problem.