# Why cannot I install Viber on my Ununtu mate 18.04?

Tags: viber

I tried installing viber on my ubuntu mate 18.04 but I couldn't. It is showing some dependency errors regarding "Package libcurl3 is not installed."
[viber installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uofDc.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete terminal output instead of a summary. If you are following instructions to install Viber, a link to those instructions would be helpful, as would a pointer to exactly where you encountered the problem (if it's not clear from the context).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to install Viber](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber)