# Unable to Install Viber due to missing libssl1.0.0 package

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, deb, viber

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04. I'm aware of the question [Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to install Viber](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber), but when I try to install via

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

I get this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package viber.
(Reading database ... 206700 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (10.3.0.37) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libssl1.0.0; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package viber (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber
```

I have tried the Viber Unofficial snap, but I ran into the huge screen rez and I don't know how to fix that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Viber's Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.viber.Viber) solves the issue:

To Install:

```
flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
```

To Run:

```
flatpak run com.viber.Viber
```

Answer (score 12):

for all the people out there who do not like to install the flatpak version and want to stick to the deb version, there is another way: since new versions of Ubuntu are shipped with `libssl1.1` or have this package in their repositories, `viber.deb` can be tinkered to state `libssl1.1` as a dependency.

I cannot guarantee 100% that all dependencies are met, but retro-compatibility should function. I have also applied this method and so far I do not have any problem on Xubuntu 19.10.

Here is a short walkthrough:

1. Ensure that `libssl1.1` is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install libssl1.1
   ```

   **Note:** if a newer version of `libssl` is available, this should be used further on on step 4.
2. Download `viber.deb` from the [Viber webpage](https://www.viber.com/download/) and copy it to a temp folder. I have used `/home/<user>/temp` for this.
3. Now we need to make some changes to the package, following this [guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies#answer-383958).

   ```
   mkdir viber
   cd viber 
   ar x ../viber.deb
   tar xzf control.tar.gz
   ```

   Line by line this does the following:

   - Creates a new folder named `viber`.
   - Moves to the new folder.
   - Unpacks `viber.deb`.
   - Unpacks `control.tar.gz`.
4. Now we need to change dependencies:

   - Open the `control` file with a text editor.
   - Change on line 6: `libssl1.0.0` to `libssl1.1`.

     **Note:** in case of newer version of `libssl` use the new version (see step 1!).
   - Save the file and exit.
5. Repackage the `.deb` file.

   ```
   tar --ignore-failed-read -cvzf control.tar.gz {post,pre}{inst,rm} md5sums control
   ar rcs viber-new.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
   ```
6. Install the new deb:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i viber-new.deb
   ```

Voila!

Comment: this works perfectly. Only thing is repackaging command is referencing data.tar.gz but the deb file I downloaded required it to be data.tar.xz so `ar rcs viber-new.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.xz` works perfectly

Answer (score 11):

**Viber installation on Ubuntu 19.04, 19.10, 20.04**

Download libssl1.0.0 deb package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com) and install it before installing viber (18.04 repository still contains it).

You could install this package by executing the next commands:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
```

Go to folder with viber (`cd ~/Downloads`, for example) and install viber:

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

Run the next command if viber depends on some other packages that have not been installed on your system yet:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

If you've encountered some viber launching issues (viber starts and crashes), then try to change display manager (to gdm3, for example):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 19.04 as one of the commenters says.

Comment: executing the commands solved the libssl nightmare for me. Thanks!  (20.04)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found working for Ubuntu is here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

This installs the official Viber.

BUT make sure to fix the package version from 6.2 to 5.3!

Here the fixed commands:

```
$ wget -O ~/viber.deb https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
$ sudo apt install gdebi-core
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb 
$ sudo gdebi ~/viber.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to download viber.AppImage from viber.com. Just download it, make it executable and run it.
It is kind of workaround because it does not make any installation, but it works with 20.04. No installation, no dependencies.