# How to install Edimax AC 600 Wi-Fi adapter drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

How do I install drivers for Edimax AC 600 Wi-Fi adapter drivers?
I went on [their website](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/au/download/for_home/wireless_adapters/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811utc) and there are no drivers for the newer versions of the kernel 5.4.0
Is there a way to install ***generic drivers*** 
(currently I don't see the Wi-Fi/Wireless icon in network settings on Ubuntu).

If anyone finds them could you please include a step by step install (I'm a newbie on Linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This device seems to have a realtek ac chipset from the rtl88xxau family.
It would be useful to provide the stdout of

```
lsusb
```

You can try to install the following dkms package:

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

In case it does not work, install the drivers from aircrack-ng github repository (and you will also have monitor mode)

```
sudo apt install git build-essential bc libelf-dev 
git clone  https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

*edit*: There is another set of repositories that provide drivers for many unsupported Realtek USB WiFi chips (including the rtl8812). I strongly recommend to use this solution from now on.
[morrownr repository](https://github.com/morrownr?tab=repositories)

```
sudo apt install git build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-amd64
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629.git
cd  8812au-20210629
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: got this: `/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_br_ext.c:25:10: fatal error: net/ipx.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Some information: https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5977740.html  Try with this fork: https://github.com/drygdryg/rtl8188eus

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! For me, the ``aircrack-ng/rtl8812au`` driver worked for my Edimax AC 600 (device ID ``7392:a812``) on Debian 11, whereas the ``morrownr/8812au-20210629`` does not seem to support this specific device ID.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this adapter to check if the next will work, but you could try:

- Install libssl1.0.0 package as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161919/925971)

  ```
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  ```
- Follow [this link](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/) and download 4.15 kernel packages:

  ```
  Build for amd64 succeeded (see BUILD.LOG.amd64):   
    linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb   
    linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb    
    linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install them: `sudo apt install ./linux-*deb`
- [Load into](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229846/925971) the older kernel
- Reinstall your driver

You could also go to:

**Show Applications** gnome menu -> Enter into **Search** field **Additional** keyword and open **Additional Drivers** (opened tab in **Software & Updates** window will appear). Look if there's no your wifi-drivers present.

Comment: Reading package lists... Error!
E: Archive is too short
When i run sudo apt install ./linux-*.deb i get error :                   E: Could not read meta data from /home/tim/Downloads/linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Second option worked - I found drivers and aplied changes + rebooted but I still can't use the device. It doesn't show up wi-fi section in network settings

Comment: I've just deployed 20.04 on VirbualBox VM and tried to install those kernel packages. It required libssl1.0.0, so I've installed it and then repeated `sudo apt install ./linux-*.deb` command again. And as a result, 4.15.0 kernel have been installed