# Unable to make Viber call on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04, viber

I am unable to make/answer viber calls on Ubuntu 20.04.

I downloaded viber.deb from https://www.viber.com/en/download/ and tried to install it using gdebi. On installation it showed that the libssl1.0.0 is missing, so I downloaded and installed `libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb`, `libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb` and `openssl1.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb`. After that I succesfully installed and activated viber on my laptop so I tried to make a call but it never gets to ringing, just stuck on calling.

[image: Stuck on calling]

Also, when someone calls me, I cannot answer the call on laptop. It rings normally, but does not react to my clicking on the answer button.

The same dependencies were missing on Ubuntu 19.04, but I was able to make a call after installing the libssl1.0 packages.

I tried editing dependencies in viber/DEBIAN/control and changed libssl1.0.0 to libssl1.1 (following instructions from [Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to install Viber](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber?rq=1) ) with the same end result- still not able to make a call.

Downloaded viber.rpm and repackaged it using alien to deb and installed it but the problem persists

Normally installed and activated viber on my Linux Mint 19.1 machine and it's working there

Comment: Solution for deb installation here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux Please also inform the viber support here: https://help.viber.com/en/contact
so they update properly the deb installation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the current official DEB-package (Viber v12.0) on Kubuntu 20.04. Any of the following should work:

1. Installing "viber-unofficial" with snap. Both stable (v0.1 corresponds to Viber 7.0) and edge channel (v10.3). The first one has the same issue with calls. The second one is crashing

   - Qt issues:

     ```
     snap qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
     ```
2. Installing "viber-mtd" with snap. It is crashing with QT issue and ALSA issue:

   ```
   Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /snap/viber-mtd/17/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory..


   ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.
   ```
3. Installing with Viber v12.0 flatpack:

   ```
   flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
   flatpak run com.viber.Viber
   ```

This way it works well! Both video and sound.

Comment: tray icon: flatpak override --user --own-name='org.kde.*' com.viber.Viber

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.

Comment: For me works just fine

Comment: Thank you, method 3 works, maybe you should add flatpak setup guide link: https://flatpak.org/setup/Kubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues. Deb from Arch repo works on my Kubuntu 20.04
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/viber/